# Password reset script only fires half the time

Tags: php, mysql

I had an inefficient piece of code for resetting passwords based on a user entering either their username or their email address. The PHP script branched depending on the identifier used. I collapsed it into one which now works if the user enters their username but not if they enter their email address. Here is the salient code:

```
$identifier = isset($_POST["username"])?"username":"email";
$ident = isset($_POST["username"])?trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,(check_chars_username($_POST["username"])))):trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, (check_chars_email($_POST["email"]))));


    //create and issue the query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM aromaMaster WHERE $identifier = '$ident'";
    $sql_res =mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_res) == 0) {
      //wrong login info
      header("Location: password_reset_form.html/error=$ident");
      exit();
    }
      $info = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res);
        $userid = $info["id"];
        $username = stripslashes($info["username"]);
        $email = stripslashes($info["email"]);
```

I have checked and doubled checked that the email form field is called email and it is. It's got me scratching my head. Particularly interesting is the header redirect. When I enter an email address and am redirected, the variable $ident appears empty.

Comment: Either run this through some debugger (PHP + Zend?) or at least echo $identifier and $ident after they are set to make sure they are what they are supposed to be.

Comment: In future just leave out the tags in the title. It clutters the question.

Comment: @e.c.h.o.: will do, sorry.
@igro: As I said, I did append $ident to the query string, and it showed up empty.  However, on trying $identifier, for some reason it said "username".  I guess isset was the wrong test - changed it to !empty() and it works great.  Thanks!

Comment: @chibineku, If it works now, you should post your solution as an answer (not as a comment to the question), and accept that as your answer.

Comment: Can you update the post and give the code for the HTML?

Comment: I want to acccept igro's answer as the correct answer, but I can't mark a comment as answer and I don't want to deny him/her their rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted in your comment, you have to check for the `username` variable of the `$_POST` array to be empty.

It's also a good idea to check if the variable is even there in the first place in addition to and before you test against it being blank.

```
$identifier = 
 (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"])) ? "username":"email";
```

When you're sending your form across, all of the text input fields will come through, even if they're blank. Blank is not the same as empty. That's the reason the first part of the ternary operator is always `true` in your initial code.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I might add that this could be simplified to `$identifier = ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'username' ] ) ) ? 'username' : 'email';` - using `isset` and `! empty` is in this case a bit redundant.